# Output selected button value or name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get values from the button and output in the window what has been selected, for me says array is **undefined**.

Please help correct my mistake.

```
<input type="radio" name="flavor" id="vanilla" value="Vanilla" checked="checked" />Vanilla 
<input type="radio" name="flavor" id="choc" value="Chocolate" />Chocolate
<input type="radio" name="flavor" id="strawberry" value="Strawberry" />Strawberry

var flavorArray = ["","","Vanilla","Chocolate","Strawberry"];

var flavorValue = document.querySelector('input[name = "flavor"]:checked').value;

flavorArray[flavorvalue]  -<< my output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="radio" name="flavor" id="vanilla" value="Vanilla" checked="checked"/>Vanilla 
        <input type="radio" name="flavor" id="choc" value="Chocolate" />Chocolate
        <input type="radio" name="flavor" id="strawberry" value="Strawberry"/>Strawberry


    <script>

         var flavorArray = ["","","Vanilla","Chocolate","Strawberry"];
         var flavorValue = document.querySelector('input[name="flavor"]:checked').value;

         console.log(flavorArray[flavorArray.indexOf(flavorValue)])
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the value as a key. That's why it's undefined.

if you did flavorArray[2], it would give you "Vanilla".
but you're saying the index is "Vanilla" so it is saying undefined.

flavorValue will give you whatever element is checked that has the name flavor

Comment: But i wouldnt know which one user selected how would i do that? if i put flavorarray[2] it will put what i wrote, how can i post which button been selected and name of that value

Answer (score 0):

```
var flavorArray = ["","","Vanilla","Chocolate","Strawberry"];

var flavorValue = document.querySelector('input[name = "flavor"]:checked').value;
console.log(flavorValue ) //GIVES you the value
console.log(flavorArray.indexOf(flavorValue) ) //Gives you the index number of that value in your flavourArray if( -1) then value not exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the checked value place in the array. And user selected value.its match with index of the array.And retrieve the index value with respected index.

```js
function check(){
  var flavorArray = ["","","Vanilla","Chocolate","Strawberry"];

var flavorValue = document.querySelector('input[name = "flavor"]:checked').value;
 for(var i=0; i<flavorArray.length; i++){
  if( flavorValue ==  flavorArray[i])
    {console.log('Matched index is' +i)
      console.log('value is'+flavorArray[i])
    }
   
   }
 
  }
check();
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="flavor" id="vanilla" value="Vanilla" checked="checked" onclick="check()"/>
<input type="radio" name="flavor" id="choc" value="Chocolate" onclick="check()"/>
<input type="radio" name="flavor" id="strawberry" value="Strawberry" onclick="check()"/>
```